# python writing classes special list

Tags: python, class

I am new to python and I am typing to write a class ""specialList"". SpecialList is a class that has two instance variables, value_list and size, value_list refers to a list, and size stores an integer representing the maximum number of items that can be stored in the list.
This is what I have done so far:

```
class SpecialList:
"""A list that can hold a limited number of items."""

    def __init__(self, size):
    """ (SpecialList, int)
    >>> L = SpecialList(10)
    >>> L.size
    10
    >>> L.value_list
    []
    """
    # complete this code





    def push_value(self, new_value):
    """ (SpecialList, object) -> NoneType

    Append new_value to this list, if there is enough space in the list according to its maximum size.  
    If there is insufficient space, new_value should not be added to the list.

    >>> L = SpecialList(10)
    >>> L.push_value(3)
    >>> L.value_list
    [3]
    """
    # complete this code



    def pop_most_recent_value(self):
    """ (SpecialList) -> object

    Precondition: len(self.value_list) != 0

    Return the value added most recently to value_list and remove it from the list.

    >>> L = SpecialList(10)
    >>> L.push_value(3)
    >>> L.push_value(4)
    >>> L.value_list
    [3, 4]
    >>> L.pop_most_recent_value()
    4
    """
    # complete this code



    def compar(self, other):
    """ (SpecialList, SpecialList) -> int
    Return 0 if both SpecialList objects have lists of the same size.
    Return 1 if self's list contains more items than other's list.
    Return -1 if self's list contains fewer items than other's list.



    """
    # complete this code
    self.other = []

    if range(len(self.value_list)) == range(len(self.other)):
        return 0
    elif range(len(self.value_list)) > len(self.other):
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

Everything works fine, but for the last part, def compare, I don't get the right score..
Please help

Comment: Why are you using `range()`?

Comment: New style classes should inherit from `object`. e.g. `class SpecialList(object)`.

Answer (score 0):

A few modifications to your `compare` method:

- Get rid of range.
- Get rid of `self.other = []`
- `other` is an instance of `SpecialList`. So you need to
  compare `self`'s `value_list` and `other`s' `value_list`.

Try this:

```
if len(self.value_list) == len(other.value_list):
    return 0
elif len(self.value_list) > len(other.value_list):
    return 1
else:
    return -1
```

Comment: This is the answer, but maybe you could also add handling for null lists.

Comment: @user1474424 Wouldn't the if condition take care if both/either objects' value_list are null?